# ulong, bitmask and bit shift in PHP from C#

Tags: c#, php, bit-shift, bit-masks, ulong

Ok so my problem is that I've to "*process*" a big integer from an endpoint response. This is a **hash** and I've to do some bit mask and bit shifts in order to view this data (it's a version: major, minor, build, etc) in a human readable way.

In **C#** I've easily written few lines to do this *processing*:

```
/// Endpoint data
ulong data = 567454918934921216;

ulong major = (version & 0xFFFF000000000000L) >> 48;
ulong minor = (version & 0x0000FFFF00000000L) >> 32;
ulong build = (version & 0x00000000FFFF0000L) >> 16;
ulong revision = version & 0x000000000000FFFFL;

string human = $"{major}.{minor}.{build}.{revision}";
Console.WriteLine(human);

/// Returns '2016.318.1322.0'
```

However this should be part of a backend task **running on a server**, so I've to write it in **PHP**. The problem is that PHP handle that big integer (`data`) as `float` cutting a significant part of it (and I need *every single bit* for doing that processing).

So the question is: **how can I "port" that C# code in *normal* PHP?**

> Important notice: I cannot access PHP installation or modifiy server
>   architecture/configuration. So I can't shift to 64bit to handle bigger
>   integer or install plugins.

Answer (score 0):

PHP int size is platform-dependent. You need 64-bit hardware AND the 64-bit version of PHP to get native 64-bit integer. You can get 64-bit integer from 32-bit integers using bitwise operators. For example: to build `0xfffffffffffffffe` you can use `(0xffffffff << 32) | 0xfffffffe`

Comment: Yes but I cannot access PHP installation, because is a production server with sites and wordpress